# How to XPATH select a list of Uncles

Tags: xpath

Im kind of new to xpath, so... sorry in advance if something is not referred to accurately...
I would like to formulate an xpath query which will select the 'uncle' of each element of a specific name:

Say I have the following XML:

```
    <aaa>
        <bbb>
            <first_uncle>
                uncle_bob
            </first_uncle>
            <ccc>
                <ddd>d_val_1</ddd>
            </ccc>
            <ccc>
                <ddd>d_val_2</ddd>
            </ccc>
            <ccc>
                <ddd>d_val_3</ddd>
            </ccc>
       </bbb>
        <bbb>
            <first_uncle>
                uncle_jack
            </first_uncle>
            <ccc>
                <ddd>d_val_4</ddd>
            </ccc>
            <ccc>
                <ddd>d_val_5</ddd>
            </ccc>
       </bbb>
   </aaa>
```

I would like to have an output which lists the 'first_uncle' of each `ddd`.
Something like this:

```
uncle_bob
uncle_bob
uncle_bob
uncle_jack
uncle_jack
```

My trials (`//ccc/ddd/../../*[1]`) gave me a list of 'unique uncles':

```
uncle_bob
uncle_jack
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your trials

Comment: Thanks @JaSON, I got this ```//ccc/ddd/../../*[1]```

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 1.0, a single XPath expression can only select a set of actual nodes. It can't select the same nodes multiple times, and there are only two `first_uncle`s in your XML.

So you would need to do this in two steps (pseudocode, since you haven't told us what language or XML library you're using):

```
var people = doc.select('/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd');

foreach (var person in people) {
   var uncle = person.selectSingle('../../first_uncle');

   // use uncle
}
```